# Django Deploy trouble

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Well, i've walking around this for a couples of days now... I think is time to ask for some help, i think my installation is ok...
Server OS: Centos 5
Python -v 2.6.5
Django -v (1, 1, 1, 'final', 0)

my apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/workshop
    ServerName taller.antell.com.py
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/workshop/workshop.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess taller.antell.com.py user=ignacio group=ignacio processes=2 threads=25
    ErrorLog /opt/workshop/apache.error.log
    CustomLog /opt/workshop/apache.custom.log combined

    <Directory "/opt/workshop">
            Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my mod_wsgi conf:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/workshop')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'workshop.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp/.python-eggs'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler( )
```

the error that i'm getting on my apache error log is:

```
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] mod_wsgi (pid=11459): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/workshop/workshop.wsgi'.
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 134, in get_response
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 40, in technical_500_response
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 114, in get_traceback_html
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return t.render(c)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 178, in render
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 779, in render
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 81, in render_node
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     raise wrapped
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught an exception while rendering: No module named vehicles
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] 
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] Original Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 71, in render_node
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     result = node.render(context)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 87, in render
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     output = force_unicode(self.filter_expression.resolve(context))
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 572, in resolve
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 687, in date
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return format(value, arg)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 269, in format
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return df.format(format_string)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 175, in r
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     s = unicode(s)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 201, in __unicode_cast
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 62, in ugettext
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return real_ugettext(message)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 286, in ugettext
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in do_translate
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 194, in translation
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 180, in _fetch
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     app = import_module(appname)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     __import__(name)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] ImportError: No module named vehicles
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] 
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] mod_wsgi (pid=11463): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/workshop/workshop.wsgi'.
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 73, in get_response
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 56, in process_request
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     if (not _is_valid_path(request.path_info) and
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 142, in _is_valid_path
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     urlresolvers.resolve(path)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 303, in resolve
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 218, in resolve
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 216, in resolve
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 245, in _get_url_patterns
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 240, in _get_urlconf_module
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]   File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122]     __import__(name)
[Wed Apr 21 15:17:48 2010] [error] [client 190.128.226.122] ImportError: No module named vehicles.urls
```

Please give my a hand, i stuck... Obviously is a problem with my vehicle module (the only one in the app), another thing is that when i try:

```
[root@localhost workshop]# python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

The app runs perfectly, i think that the problem is something near the wsgi conf, something is not clicking....

Tks...

Update:
workshop dir looks like...

```
[root@localhost workshop]# ls -l
total 504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22706 Apr 21 15:17 apache.custom.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 408141 Apr 21 15:17 apache.error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Apr 17 10:56 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    124 Apr 21 11:09 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    542 Apr 17 10:56 manage.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3326 Apr 17 10:56 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2522 Apr 21 11:09 settings.pyc
drw-r--r-- 4 root root   4096 Apr 17 10:56 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    381 Apr 21 13:42 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    398 Apr 21 13:00 urls.pyc
drw-r--r-- 2 root root   4096 Apr 21 13:44 vehicles
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38912 Apr 17 10:56 workshop.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    263 Apr 21 15:30 workshop.wsgi
```

vehicles dir

```
[root@localhost vehicles]# ls -l
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  390 Apr 17 10:56 admin.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  967 Apr 21 13:00 admin.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  732 Apr 17 10:56 forms.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2086 Apr 21 13:00 forms.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 17 10:56 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  133 Apr 21 11:36 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  936 Apr 17 10:56 models.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1827 Apr 21 11:36 models.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  514 Apr 17 10:56 tests.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  989 Apr 21 13:44 tests.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1035 Apr 17 10:56 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1935 Apr 21 13:00 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3164 Apr 17 10:56 views.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4081 Apr 21 13:00 views.pyc
```

Update 2: this is my settings.py

```
# Django settings for workshop project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('Ignacio Rojas', 'ignacio@antell.com.py'),
    ('Fabian Biedermann', 'fabian@antell.com.py'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3' 
DATABASE_NAME = '/opt/workshop/workshop.db'
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''
DATABASE_PORT = ''

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Asuncion'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-py'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '11y0_jb=+b4^nq@2-fo#g$-ihk5*v&d5-8hg_y0i@*9$w8jalp'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'workshop.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/opt/workshop/templates"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'workshop.vehicles',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)
```

This is what outputs on the test of:
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

```
__name__ = settings
__file__ = /opt/django/workshop/settings.pyc
os.getpid() = 7207
os.getcwd() = /opt/django/workshop
os.curdir = .
sys.path = ['/opt/django', '/opt/django/workshop', '/opt/django/workshop', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
sys.modules.keys() = ['copy_reg', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', 'encodings.__builtin__', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'codecs', 'os.path', 'settings', 'signal', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'os']
sys.modules.has_key('workshop') = False
__name__ = workshop.settings
__file__ = /opt/django/workshop/settings.pyc
os.getpid() = 7207
os.getcwd() = /opt/django/workshop
os.curdir = .
sys.path = ['/opt/django', '/opt/django/workshop', '/opt/django/workshop', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
sys.modules.keys() = ['django.core.exceptions', 'django.core.management.django', 'copy_reg', 'sre_compile', 'django.conf.os', 'locale', '_sre', 'functools', 'encodings', 'django.conf.global_settings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'django.core.management', 'django.core.management.sys', 'django.utils.functional', '__main__', 'operator', 'encodings.encodings', 'django.utils.re', 'django.core.management.imp', 'django.core.management.color', 'abc', 'posixpath', 'django.utils', 'imp', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', 'gettext', 'sre_constants', 'django.conf', 're', '_abcoll', 'types', 'django.utils.importlib', '_codecs', 'django.core.management.optparse', 'django.core.management.base', '_struct', '_warnings', 'django.conf.django', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', 'encodings.__builtin__', 'string', 'django.utils.termcolors', 'warnings', 'optparse', 'UserDict', 'struct', 'encodings.utf_8', 'django.utils.sys', 'textwrap', 'sys', 'django.django', 'codecs', 'django.utils.version', 'django.utils.os', 'copy', 'workshop.settings', 'os.path', 'strop', '_functools', '_locale', 'django.conf.time', 'django.conf.re', 'workshop.sys', 'settings', 'workshop', 'signal', 'django.core', 'django.utils.django', 'django', 'django.core.management.os', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'time', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', 'workshop.os']
sys.modules.has_key('workshop') = True
sys.modules['wokshop'].__name__ = workshop
sys.modules['workshop'].__file__ = /opt/django/workshop/__init__.pyc
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = workshop.settings
```

new wsgi:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/django/workshop')
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/django')

import settings

import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ( settings)
utility = django.core.management.ManagementUtility( )
command = utility.fetch_command( 'runserver')

command.validate( )

import django.conf
import django.utils

django.utils.translation.activate( django.conf.settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler( )
```

Solved with:

```
chmod -R 755 workshop && chown -R apache:apache workshop
```

Comment: Can you show your directory structure? In particular, do you by any chance have a second `workshop` directory inside your main `workshop` dir, which contains the actual apps?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  apache.custom.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  apache.error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  manage.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  settings.pyc
drw-r--r-- 4 root root  templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  urls.pyc
drw-r--r-- 2 root root  vehicles
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  workshop.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  workshop.wsgi

Comment: Try flattening that out with `ls -1`, and edit your question so we can see it.  The formatting is all wrong because of the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding both the directory containing the settings.py file and its parent directory to sys.path. Better still, read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html' and use the WSGI script file contents described right at the end (after you have read the post as to why it is an issue). :-)

---

UPDATE 1

In another comment you post your permissions as 'drw-r--r-- 2 root root vehicles'.

The 'x' bit isn't set on the directory for anyone. This will cause anything to fail which needs to be able to generate a directory listing to see what is in the directory.

In other words, look at all your directory permissions and fix things up to be 'drwxr-xr-x'.

Also, because you have made directories owned by root, if your application needs to write to any directories it will not be able to.

In summary, directory/file permissions issues.

Comment: it;s kinda embarassing but a chmod -R 755 workshop && chown -R apache:apache workshop solved the case... Thanks all of you guys!

Comment: man, this saved my day. totally different problem though.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your path is actually `/opt/workshop/workshop/`

So in your wsgi file you should have `sys.path.append('/opt/workshop/workshop')`
And if that's not the case, than `workshop.settings` should be `settings` instead.

[edit]
The way I see it you have 3 options.

1. Add `opt` to sys.path so `workshop.urls` and such work (bad idea imho since `opt` could include anything`
2. Remove `workshop` from all paths
3. Move the Python code to a `workshop` (or something else) directory (make sure it contains an `__init__.py`)

Personally I would take option 3 since otherwise you'll be mixing your python apps with the rest (media, templates, etc...)

Comment: It can't be /opt/workshop/workshop/ or apache would not be outputting logs into the directory he did an `ls` on.

Comment: I think it's the latter. If his /opt/workshop is on the system path, then the /opt/workshop/workshop directory structure would actually work - at least the settings module would be at workshop.settings anyway.

Comment: That is true Jack M. In that case it's probably the settings that's killing it now :)

Comment: Would the fact that `vehicles.__init__.py` is empty have any bearing on it?

Comment: You'll have to probably also change your vehicles module from 'workshop.vehicles' to just 'vehicles' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting as well.

Comment: __init__.py can be empty - the presence of an __init__.py file just tells python that the directory is a python module. It can optionally contain module-level functions and docstrings just like any python file, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: all my app is in /opt/workshop, example: /opt/workshop/settings.py, so the path /opt/workshop/workshop doesn't exists... i tried put 'settings' only and didnt work either, still getting 500 error

Comment: My error changed to:
    ImportError: No module named vehicles

Comment: That might be an improvement - if this changed after changing DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to simply `'settings'`, now change the vehicles module in INSTALLED_APPS from `'workshop.vehicles'` to `'vehicles'`

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache if you make any changes to your .wsgi or settings files.